# Page Speed Insights: SPA receives 66/100 on mobile however 0/100 on desktop

Tags: seo, google-pagespeed, google-insights

I've created a single page application using AngularJS but noticed that on desktop the Google Page Speed Insights is ranking the Desktop as 0/100 even though there is no change between scripts/optimisations etc on Desktop and Mobile.

I use server-side rendering to help with Google to index my pages better, but again, this doesn't differentiate on Desktop.

Will this affect ranking and are the results here reliable, and also why is PSI making it 0/100 when it is the same script.

**Mobile:**

[image: Snapshot of the results from mobile]

**Desktop:**

[image: Snapshot of the results from desktop]

Comment: i suspect an issue with desktop user agents.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on this @Evgeniy? Is this issue programmatic, i.e. because of PHP?

Comment: its just a guess - it seems to me, using mobile user agent, the cache (pre-rendered version) is loaded pretty properly. But in case of desktop agent something goes weirdly wrong - like the cache is not delivered at all.

Comment: That's very strange. Google is rendering the site fully in the preview on the right hand side of the PSI.

Comment: i would try to load the page with different user agents, i.e. with webpagetest.org and look into loading times of second and third run, where the cache is loading. Maybe your pre-rendering engine has problems with Googles user agent? Try to run your browser as googlebot...

Comment: Hi, please share your application URL. Need to test and debug

Answer (score 2):

Google does **NOT** use **Google Pagespeed**, **Google Insights** or **Google Lighthouse** to determine your rankings, so those scores... are meaningless for real-world ranking purposes.

In terms of rankings, what really matters is that the page renders on both smartphones, tablets and desktop computers, you test this using **Google Fetch** which can be found within the **Google Search Console**.

Asides that you should make sure your pages are quick, 99% of the time this is down to hosting, even poorly coded websites can render within 1 second with excellent hosting.

Google rewards fast websites and strongly believes speed has a major impact on user experience and bounce rate:

[image]

***Summary...***

Bad scores on websites that evaluate and issue virtual scores have little to no bearing on your website unless you have fundamental problems.

Comment: Thanks for this. Very insightful, however, this does not explain why PSI is giving 0/100 on Desktop.

Comment: `Will this affect ranking and are the results here reliable?` <--- your concern was your rankings, not why. As I said, use Google Fetch, if it works, then its insights obviously having a problem with your site, but who cares, Google doesn't use it. If you want every online app to work on your website, then you don't use `AngularJS`, fact. Online apps struggle with a lot of AngularJS SPA based frameworks, but you should never get a 0/100 since you should be using good practices for users or bots without JavaScript, e.g NoScript or a .no-js trigger, even if its a notice saying not supported.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps a side-question of why is it 0/100 on Desktop when it is the same script. The question has been edited.